# with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc: IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename:

Tags: python-2.7

What I'm trying to do is changing a file from one place to another.

Here is the code :

```
print ("Loading system, please wait 5 seconds.")

try:
    import os, sys
    # Path to be created
    path = "C:\Windows2" # Just a testing random file...
    os.mkdir( path, 0755 );

except:
    print 'Path already created. Passing...'


import shutil
src = data_path =  os.path.expanduser('~')+ '\Desktop\admin.dll'
dst = data_path = "C:\Windows2"
shutil.move(src, dst)
```

But then, I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\youse\Desktop\TESTING.py", line 16, in <module>
    shutil.move(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 316, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 144, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 96, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\youse\\Desktop\x07dmin.dll'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use double-backslash to denote a literal backslash in a quoted string.

```
src = data_path =  os.path.expanduser('~')+ '\\Desktop\\admin.dll'
dst = data_path = "C:\\Windows2"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You've helped , I spent hours looking at it and I just needed double, thank you again!